# System.OutOfMemoryException in Mvc Application with .less file

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, less, out-of-memory

In our website sometimes i am getting System.OutOfMemoryException and in log files i can see that cause of http://mywebsite/Assets/less/layout.less?3632.01 And details of error is below :

```
Error Caught in Application_Error event
Error in: http://mywebsite/Assets/less/layout.less?3632.01
Error Message:Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.
Stack Trace: 
    at System.String.ReplaceInternal(String oldValue, String newValue) 
    at System.String.Replace(String oldValue, String newValue) 
    at dotless.Core.Parser.Tokenizer.SetupInput(String input, String fileName) at dotless.Core.Parser.Parser.Parse(String input, String fileName) 
    at dotless.Core.LessEngine.TransformToCss(String source, String fileName) at dotless.Core.CacheDecorator.TransformToCss(String source, String fileName) 
    at dotless.Core.ParameterDecorator.TransformToCss(String source, String fileName) at dotless.Core.HandlerImpl.Execute() 
    at dotless.Core.LessCssHttpHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) 
    at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() 
    at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

Less file's size is 475KB. And is it normal as a less file ?

Comment: IMHO,  your less file is way too big.[ I would split a less/css file if it is longer than 10kb ] I am assuming it is a single file, not concatenation of multiple files. 
btw, what  exactly  your website does that it requires heavy less (and ofcourse much heavier css,)?